# How do i place my footer component pinned at the end of the browser?

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I'm trying to build a basic website as my first project using React and Tailwind CSS. I have made three components namely - Header, Input and Footer in my react app. My header is placed at the top by default. Next comes my input component where I take input from user and want this component to fill the rest of the space with input fields center middle top. I want my footer to be pinned to bottom.

This is what I want to achieve exactly.

[Required Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BGR9K.png)

Below is my react code:

App.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import Header from "./components/Header";
import Footer from './components/Footer';
import Input from './components/Input';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className='flex flex-col min-h-screen'>
    <Header />
    <Input />
    <Footer />
    </div>
  )
}
```

Header.jsx:

```
import React from 'react';

function Header() {
    return (
        <div className='basis-full mt-5 mb-5'>
            <h1 className="text-5xl font-bold text-center text-blue-1">
                Grocery Tracker
            </h1>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Header;
```

Input.jsx:

```
import React from 'react';

function Input(){
  return(

    <div className='flex justify-evenly'>
      <form action="/" method="post">
      <label  for="itemName">Enter your item: </label>
      <input className="border border-gray-500 focus:border-black cursor-text px-2 ml-2 mr-2" autoFocus type="text" name="items" id="items" placeholder="Tomatoes, Milk, Atta etc."/>
      <label  for="itemQuantity">Enter item quantity: </label>
      <input className="border border-gray-500 focus:border-black cursor-text px-2 ml-2 mr-2" autoFocus type="text" name="items" id="items" placeholder="1 Kg, 2 Packets, 500 ml etc."/>
      <label  for="itemPrice">Enter thr price: </label>
      <input className="border border-gray-500 focus:border-black cursor-text px-2 ml-2 mr-2" autoFocus type="number" name="items" id="items" placeholder="Rs. 100, Rs. 56, Rs. 47 etc."/>
      </form>
      </div>
  )
}

export default Input;
```

Also, when i add `flex-grow` property to my input flex, then the `justify-evenly` is not working.

Footer.jsx:

```
import React from 'react';
import indianFlag from '../images/ind.jpg';

function Footer(){
  return(
    <div className='flex items-end pt-2 justify-center end gap-2 mb-5'>
        <div>
            <p text-color='black'>
                Copyright© 2023 | Made in Vizag, India  
            </p>
        </div>
        <div>
        <img height='30px' width='30px' src={indianFlag} alt='Indian Flag' />
        </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Footer;
```

[My current Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qYKxR.png)

Comment: This is ultimately an HTML and CSS question and would be better presented as such. You can then apply a solution to your React app.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this, first add `position:relative` to the `body`.
Update the styles in `Footer.jsx` like this

```
import React from 'react';
import indianFlag from '../images/ind.jpg';

function Footer(){
  return(
    <div className='absolute bottom-0 w-full pt-2 mb-5'>
        <div>
            <p text-color='black'>
                Copyright© 2023 | Made in Vizag, India  
            </p>
        </div>
        <div>
        <img height='30px' width='30px' src={indianFlag} alt='Indian Flag' />
        </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Footer;
```

This will pin your footer to the very bottom of the page.

Comment: You can add `position: relative` in your custom CSS file

Answer (score 0):

You can use some "generic" CSS and `grid` which gives us the "holy grail" view with a header, left / main/ right and footer - just un-comment what you need/include on your page.  I added some color and comments in the CSS to help with understanding what is where.

Note: I used `grid-areas:` but also put in and commented out the `grid-column:` if that is the way you wish to say what is where.

No header or sides: just un-comment a side for example if you need it.

```css
html,
body,*{
  /* use full screen */
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.parent-container {
  min-height: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr auto;
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr auto;
  grid-template-areas: 
  'header header header' 
  'leftside main rightside'
  'footer footer footer';

  border: solid 1px green;
}

.header {
  padding: 2rem;
  grid-area: header;
  /*  grid-column: 1 / 4;*/
}

.left-side {
  grid-area: leftside;
  /*  grid-column: 1 / 2;*/
}

.main {
  grid-area: main;
  /*  grid-column: 2 / 3;*/
  display: block;
  padding: 0.25em;
  overflow: auto;
}

.right-side {
  grid-area: rightside;
  /* grid-column: 3 / 4;*/
}

.footer {
  grid-area: footer;
  /*  grid-column: 1 / 4;*/
  padding: 1em;
  /* just super center the footer */
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
}

/* just colors below here to illustrate */
.head-color {
  background-color: #FF000020;
}

.foot-color {
  background-color: #00FF0020;
}

.main-color {
  background-color: #FFB00020;
}

.left-color {
  background-color: #0000FF20;
}

.right-color {
  background-color: #FFB0FF20;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent-container">
 <!--  <div class="header section head-color">Need a head I am it!</div> -->
  <div class="main section main-color">Just Main Content no sides or header</div>
  <!--
   <div class="left-side left-color">left I am not Yoda</div>
 <div class="right-side right-color">right I am the fun guy</div>
 -->
  <div class="footer foot-color section">super centered Footer still</div>
</div>
```